# How to declare a string - modifed like an array structure - as an array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$string = '"some key" => "some value", "another key" => "anothe value"';
```

Why can't I define this as an array like;

```
$array = array($string);
```

Any help please?

Comment: You need to interpret the string, as at the moment it's just a string containing some markup which makes it look like an array.

Comment: _“Why can't I define this as an array like”_ - because there is a difference between _code_, and _data_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a json instead of array type string as below

```
$string = '{"some key" : "some value", "another key" : "anothe value"}';

     $array = array(json_decode($string));

     dd($array);
```